# SSL Connection after cert removal from store

Tags: ssl, networking, service, https

My team is writing an app which has persisted connections which are encrypted using SSL (On Windows Server). These are CA signed certificates. The CA is in our Corporate Network so controlled by the domain, but I dont think its relevant to the question.

I see that if I remove the underlying certificate from cert store (certlm.msc) the connections which were already established continue to stay alive and not teared down. Aren't these SSL connections suppose to tear down if the certificate is removed ?

This is on a Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> see that if I remove the underlying certificate from cert store (certlm.msc) the connections which were already established continue to stay alive and not teared down. Aren't these SSL connections suppose to tear down if the certificate is removed ?

No. The connections exist; the handshake is complete; there is no reason why the connection should monitor the state of the certificate store. Until the next handshake.